# How can I solve the error: Error in UseMethod("summarise")

Tags: r

So I'm running the code below in R Studio and getting this error:

> Error in UseMethod("summarise") :
> no applicable method for 'summarise' applied to an object of class "c('matrix', 'array', 'double', 'numeric')"

The code I was trying to run is:

> standardise_salary <- scale(salary[c('yrs.since.phd','yrs.service','salary')], center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

> standardise_salary %>% summarise(Min = min(Salary,na.rm = TRUE),

- ```
                              Q1 = quantile(Salary,probs = .25,na.rm = TRUE),
  ```
- ```
                              Median = median(Salary, na.rm = TRUE),
  ```
- ```
                              Q3 = quantile(Salary,probs = .75,na.rm = TRUE),
  ```
- ```
                              Max = max(Salary,na.rm = TRUE),
  ```
- ```
                              Mean = mean(Salary, na.rm = TRUE),
  ```
- ```
                              SD = sd(Salary, na.rm = TRUE),
  ```
- ```
                              n = n(), Missing = sum(is.na(Salary)))
  ```

**I don't know how to solve this, someone please assist..**

Comment: When writing a question, it is common to make a small reproducible example so that others may test your ideas/code. As it stands, nobody knows much about your data, ie. code...
BTW, Did you run `library(tidyverse)`

Comment: Okay thanks.. it’s first question on stackoverflow. No the package I used was dplyr. Found a way out, see my comment below.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `salary` is your initial dataframe, you can normalize `salary` column by using `mutate` function and then just add `summarise` to the pipeline to get the minima for the `standardise_salary` column:

```
library(dplyr)

salary %>%
  dplyr::select(salary)
  dplyr::mutate(standardise_salary= scale(salary, 
             center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)) %>%
  dplyr::summarise(Min = min(standardise_salary, na.rm=T))
```

Comment: Altough would be great to see `dput(salary)` to test if it works for your actual dataframe....

Comment: Thanks Martinez for the help. All I did to make it work was to coerce the class into a data frame, as.data.frame(standardized_salary) then ran my summarize again and that did the job.. Thank you